# Conditional Random Field feature functions

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I've been reading some papers on CRFs and am slightly confused about the feature functions. Unary (node) and binary (edge) features f are normally of the form

f(yc, xc) = 1{yc=y ̃c}fg(xc).

where {.} is the indicator function evaluating to 1 if the condition enclosed is true, and 0 otherwise. fg is a function of the data xc which extracts useful attributes (features) from the data.

Now it seems to me that to create CRF features the true labels (yc) must be known. This is true for training but for the testing phase the true class labels are unknown (since we are trying to determine their most likely value).

Am I missing something? How can this be correctly implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea with the CRF is that it assigns a score to each setting of the labels.  So what you do, notionally, is compute the scores for all possible label assignments and then whichever labeling gets the biggest score is what the CRF predicts/outputs.  This is only going to make sense if the CRF gives different scores to different label assignments.  When you think of it that way it's clear that the labels must be involved in the feature functions for this to work.

So lets say the log probability function for your CRF is F(x,y).  So it assigns a number to each combination of a data sample x and a labeling y.  So when you get a new data sample the predicted label during test time is just argmax_y F(new_x, y).  That is, you find the value of y that makes F(new_x,y) the biggest and that's the predicted labeling.

Comment: I see what you mean. So for parameter estimation that makes sense. Once you know the CRF model parameters, and you want to predict a test example, how does that work? Since the labels are unknown for a test example

Comment: You literally predict the y value that has the biggest score.  So you have to write some code that, implicitly or explicitly, computes the score for all the possibly y values and then returns whichever one got the biggest score.  That's the prediction at test time.